# I can't take this animated banner directly from Codepen. I think everything is properly linked so why won't it work?

Tags: javascript, html, gsap, tween.js

I found this cool little HTML 5 banner on codepen and wanted to play around with the javascript. However when I transcribe all of the code 'as is' each into separate docs in a common folder on my desktop none of the .js functions seems to be working. I think that either there is a problem with the .js file or that it is not pulling the TweenMax.min.js library properly. I tried downloading the library and placing into a new file on my desktop but no luck. Neither the url or the file path seem to be working. Below are examples of how I linked all of my files. Does this make sense? Can anyone please give me some advice? It would be much appreciated.

http://codepen.io/emilychadraba/pen/pvLjzm

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="codepen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="codepen.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="TweenMax.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="banner crop">

<img id="photo" src="http://bestevents.us/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/1409861249_10536823_10152285336897304_4970023981985043307_o.png"/>

<img id="beer1" class="absolute-left" src="http://www.gooseisland.com/content/gooseisland/en/goose/allBeers/_jcr_content/urbanAles/addbeer/sImage" />

<img id="beer2" class="absolute-center" src="http://www.gooseisland.com/content/gooseisland/en/goose/allBeers/_jcr_content/urbanAles/addbeer_1/sImage" />

<img id="beer3" class="absolute-right" src="http://www.gooseisland.com/content/gooseisland/en/goose/allBeers/_jcr_content/urbanAles/addbeer_0/sImage" />

<img id="logo" class= "absolute" src="http://www.gooseisland.com/assets/images/header-logo.png" </img>

<h2 id="hed1"> Introducing This Year's <br> Beverage Lineup </br> </h2>
<h2 id="hed2"> 312 Urban Block Party </h2>
<h3 id="hed3"> hosted by Goose Island </h3>
<h2 id="cta"> Join the Party </h2>
<h6 id="pale"> 312 Urban Pale Ale </h6>
<h6 id="wheat"> 312 Urban Wheat Ale </h6>
<h6 id="green"> Green Line Pale Ale </h6>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.15.1/TweenMax.min.js">   </script>
</banner> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is TweenMax.min.js there twice? And of course your example includes no HTML like the pen has

Comment: What about that closing body tag? Just a typo?

Comment: And is the missing html tag for some reason?  odd with the doctype that way and not having that...a codepen puts that around the HTML for you...

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, so#1 yes the body tag was a typo in my question. I fixed it here. #2 I added all the html I have in my document to help with confusion. #3 I put it twice to see if either one word work, I've tried each individually as well (over kill I admit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have the script trying to execute before both the TweenMax library is loaded and DOM is ready. Try the below html making sure that the codepen.js is the last elements in the body tag to make sure it is run last.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="codepen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="TweenMax.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="codepen.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are a hero! Haha I can't believe I missed that. Thank you very much good sir/mam